# How to restrict Special Characters in iOS by using xamarin?

Tags: ios, xamarin

I am working with IOS by using xamarin ,I am new to technology I have one requirement ,That is I don't want to allow any special character in my text box .How can I do this any one help me
thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use ShouldChangeCharacters delegate.
Using it you can decide weather or not to update the text of the UITextField.

For example lets say you have a UITextField named textField:

```
textField.ShouldChangeCharacters = (textField, range, replacementString) => {

                if (isSpecialCharacter) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            };
```